# Cannot include Libnm and Glib properly

Tags: c++, linux, wifi, glib

I tried to use libnm for a small hobby-tool. (a cli tool e. g. for connecting via ssid with a network)

To my setup: I use fedora linux and installed `NetworkManager-libnm-devel`. (glib was already installed and up to date) I also can find the directories of the libraries in the `/usr/include` directory. Because of that, I can write e. . `#include <libnm/NetworkManager.h>` and `#include <glib-2.0/glib.h>`. So far so good.

Now I am getting error messages saying, that all includes in these files cannot be found. (Also when compiling with `gcc main.cpp -o main.o`)

This is a error message I get:

(glib)

```
#include errors detected based on information provided by the configurationProvider setting. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (/path/to/project/src/main.cpp).C/C++(1696)
cannot open source file "glib/galloca.h" (dependency of "glib-2.0/glib.h")
```

or
(libnm)

```
cannot open source file "gio/gio.h" (dependency of "libnm/NetworkManager.h")
```

This is the only code I am using for now:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include <glib-2.0/glib.h>
#include <libnm/NetworkManager.h>

int main(const int argc, const char **argv)
{
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The only thing I could find whats to do, is here: https://developer-old.gnome.org/libnm/stable/usage.html

It's a bit sad, that there is no further explanation how to properly use this library. :( I hope that anyone can help me, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Including those files with a path relative to `/usr/include`, as in your example

```c
#include <glib-2.0/glib.h>
#include <libnm/NetworkManager.h>
```

is not how they are meant to be included, and will likely not work, because those headers include other dependent headers which won't be found relative to `/usr/include`.

In the "How to use libnm" section of the page that you linked, it shows that you must include them as

```c
#include <glib.h>
#include <NetworkManager.h>
```

and use pkg-config to get the correct compiler flags. Add `$(pkg-config --cflags --libs libnm)` to your compiler command line.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I changed the code with your suggestions. But the headers
```
#include <glib.h>
#include <NetworkManager.h>
```
cannot be found. I don't really understand why as I installed both libraries on my system and the directories of these libraries exist on my device too.

Comment: What is the output of `pkg-config --cflags --libs libnm`?

Comment: ❯ pkg-config --cflags --libs libnm
-I/usr/include/libnm -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/sysprof-4 -I/usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -pthread -lnm -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

The suggestions from @ptomato worked for the compilation of the project! Thanks!

The reason for the incorrect inclusion of the headers was simply an intellisense problem within VS code. I had updated the C/C++ extension tools, restarted VS Code and it suddenly worked.

The working project can be found here: [GitHub](https://github.com/MhouneyLH/wifi_manager)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).